# Jquery output with span id tag instead of id in table

Tags: jquery

Instead of giving Id to `table` tag, I have given Id to `span` tag. Please help how to get result with this Id.

```
<head> 
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>eq demo</title> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table border="1"> 
<span id=table1> 
<tr>
 <td>TD #0</td>
 <td>TD #1</td>
 <td>TD #2</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>TD #3</td>
 <td>TD #4</td>
 <td>TD #5</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td>TD #6</td>
 <td>TD #7</td>
 <td>TD #8</td>
</tr> 
</span> 
</table> 
<script> 
 $('#table1 td:eq(3)').css("color", "red"); 
</script> 
</body>
```

---

Comment: can you show your HTML , from what you have asked its unlear what do u wanna do actually..

Comment: Your demo leaves a lot to the imagination, please provide a jsFiddle with a working example of your code.

Comment: give id `table1` to your table and it will work as the page is rendering the span outside of the table.

Comment: span inside a table tag is invalid and the browser will remove it which is probably why your jquery does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you write such code and inspect in browser,

It pops span out of the table, means span tag will be closed before table tag as below.

```
<span id="table1"> 
      </span>
<table border="1"> 
     <tbody><tr>
        <td>TD #0</td>
        <td>TD #1</td>
        <td>TD #2</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>TD #3</td>
        <td>TD #4</td>
        <td>TD #5</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>TD #6</td>
        <td>TD #7</td>
        <td>TD #8</td>
      </tr> 

    </tbody></table>
```

So, its better to give table1 id to table itself, instead of playing around with table and span.

I hope this will solve your concern regarding.

Comment: I tried with your above code but I found it is not running. Please clarify

Comment: I clarified right ? It pops span out of the table, means span tag will be closed before table tag as below.
So, its better to give table1 id to table itself, instead of playing around with table and span.